# How to read data from a xml file on a web server

Tags: xml, cocoa, scheduling

I want to read data from a xml file placed on a web server. then I want to display this data in a UITableView. Can someone help me how can I read data from a file.

Also I need to update the data in each 30 sec.So can someone tell me how can I read that xml file in every 30 secs.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Gaurav Arora

Answer (score 0):

You might use `NSUrlConnection` to fetch the XML document from the server. Personally I think, it is more convenient to use a nice wrapper around `NSUrlConnection` to simplify your application code.

At the moment I use ASIHHTPRequest and GTM-HTTP-Fetcher in my projects. Both libraries worked quiet well for me.

After receiving the XML document, you should create an `NSXMLParser` to ingest the information. Please remind that the document based API its not available on the iPhone.

After information has been received from the server, you might think about rescheduling an new execution block using `dispatch_after` with a delay of 30 seconds to activate refetching.

I recommend to execute the remote server access and XML parsing in an background operation that does not block the UI thread managed by the main loop. As soon as new data has been received in the background, i normally use `dispatch_async()` to put an execution block onto the main (UI) queue that processes the update on the `UITableView`.